# Install rouge code highlighter on windows for jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll, rouge

I have ruby for windows installed and working on my Windows 8 64-bit laptop. I also have jekyll installed and working and am able to build and serve a static website built using jekyll.

My problem is with syntax highlighting for code snippets in markdown posts in my jekyll setup.

The default highlighter, which is pygments, requires a python install and I don't want that on my windows machine.

So I found that rogue is a native syntax highlighter in ruby, and tried to install it by issuing the following command, as told in this jekyll on windows guide page http://jekyll-windows.juthilo.com/3-syntax-highlighting/

```
gem install rouge
```

However, when I do that, I am getting the following error.

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rogue' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: logue, rogu, vogue
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated. Note that the command windows is in admin mode, and also as stated earlier, ruby and jekyll are running fine on my laptop.

[image]

Finally, I am not behind any firewall or anything like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `gem install rouge` not `gem install rogue`.

Comment: Thanks. New to ruby and this was a rookie mistake :(

Comment: @CamilStaps I tried to delete the question, but it says "Flag it for Moderator", so I have flagged it with a close vote.

Comment: @Shiva Well, I just had the exact same problem, came to this answer after googling for the problem, and I had made exactly this mistake. So as far as I am concerned, this was a very helpful question and answer :)

Comment: There you go @CamilStaps ↑↑↑